# Vehicle Fuel Level Error Detection, and Refueling Detection c# or SQL

Tags: c#, t-sql, graph, statistics

I'm readying Vehicle Fuel Levels using an electronic Fuel Stick.

I have continuous readings from a GPS device which transmits this data in 1 minute intervals. I currently store this data in my Microsoft SQL Database, and can produce nice looking graphs.

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to detect

1. Refueling Events
2. Siphoning Events

There are several issues when it comes to the readings.
There are times when each fuel level reading spikes, and comes back down to somewhere close to the previous level. This make false positives a challenge.

There are times when there are spikes for a prolonged period of time (seen after a refueling sometimes), then the fuel level decreases linearly as you would expect. See the second graph below.

I have the ODO Meter Reading, and the Fuel Level Reading (in Litres).

Given the above problems, I need a way detect these noisy samples which have a high deviation from the expected linear decrease over time.

Here is a sample of data for 2 Vehicles (as a Graph).
The Blue Line is the actual data.
The Red Line is my attempt at using a running average of 10 samples to try "smooth" out the large deviations.

[image: Fuel Level Graph for 2 Vehicles]

Now for research and ideas:
I have found 4 different methods to help identify large deviations. (I think)

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_detection
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Electric_rules
3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson_rules
4. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter

Are there any better alternatives that I should consider?

Anyone know of an implementation that can be achieved using C# or TSQL?

Any advise or ideas would be great.

Comment: Matlab is a great solution for these type problems.  You may ask the question at the Matlab forum where lots of great mathematicians answer questions.  You can create a dll in matlab and call the dll from a c# application.

Comment: A simple solution would be to remove the 10 highest and 10 lowest values and then average the remaining numbers and only look at the last 1 hour of data.

Comment: @jdweng, I don't think that will help much, as I receive 1 record per minute.
What is interesting is to check with Matlab. I have never worked with it before, but let's see what others from the Matlab forums can come up with :) Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: You can adjust the times accordingly.  Take the last X samples and remove Y max number and Z min numbers and average the rest.  It is a very simple way of solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to go about this is to formulate a model to represent how the fueling, siphoning, and noise processes work. This model will contain some free parameters (namely normal fuel use, the amount of fuel added, time duration of fueling, amount of fuel removed, duration of siphoning, and magnitude of noise fluctuations, at least). Then "detection" of events means finding the parameters which maximize the log-likelihood function LL(parameters) = log p(data|parameters). This is the best you can do -- if you could do this, you wouldn't need any other approach. Other methods might be useful as an approximation to this approach -- that's a justification for using those methods.

Since the model is discontinuous, the log-likelihood function might be discontinuous as well. Some heuristics to search for best-fit parameters might be necessary. Such heuristics might coincide with published methods -- that's great, but not necessary.

Seber & Wild, "Nonlinear Regression" has a one or more chapters on models which have discontinuities.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  However, I'm looking to understand what models are all ready available to remove the noise which causes the biggest problem.

Once the noise is gone, it means that siphoning and refueling models become trivial.  Any suggestions on which is the best approach for noise removal.  Consider that a vehicle which moves can have fluctuations of over 2 hours as seen in the second graph, which is just the nature of these fuel measuring units.  Considering also that uphills, downhills, road bumps, acceleration, deceleration + other factors all cause "noise"

Comment: "Removing the noise" is equivalent to knowing the model. Heuristics such as moving averages, etc. embody unstated assumptions about the physical mechanisms at work. What I am suggesting is to make all the assumptions explicit. Bring as many of the factors you mentioned (uphill, downhill, bumps, etc) into the model as you can.